# URL validation using eregi() but now with preg_match

Tags: php, preg-match, eregi

eregi() is deprecated and need to replace with preg_match. How can I convert following syntax into preg_match? Suppose following are url and it's required regex pattern:

```
$url = "https://james.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/my-product-final";
$urlregex = "^(https?|ftp)\:\/\/([a-zÃ¥Ã¤Ã¶Ã…Ã„Ã–Ã¦Ã†Ã¸Ã˜0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-zÃ¥Ã¤Ã¶Ã…Ã„Ã–Ã¦Ã†Ã¸Ã˜0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?[a-zÃ¥Ã¤Ã¶Ã…Ã„Ã–Ã¦Ã†Ã¸Ã˜0-9+\$_-]+(\.[a-zÃ¥Ã¤Ã¶Ã…Ã„Ã–Ã¦Ã†Ã¸Ã˜0-9+\$_-]+)*(\:[0-9]{2,5})?(\/([a-zÃ¥Ã¤Ã¶Ã…Ã„Ã–Ã¦Ã†Ã¸Ã˜0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-zÃ¥Ã¤Ã¶Ã…Ã„Ã–Ã¦Ã†Ã¸Ã˜0-9;:@/&%=+\$_.-]*)?(#[a-z_.-][a-zÃ¥Ã¤Ã¶Ã…Ã„Ã–Ã¦Ã†Ã¸Ã˜0-9+\$_.-]*)?\$";
```

Following code works fine:

```
if (eregi($urlregex, $url)) {
echo "Valid";
exit;
}
```

I tried to convert into 'preg_match' but it couldn't work:

```
if (preg_match("#$urlregex#i", $url)) {
echo "Valid";
exit;
}
```

Also tried like this:

```
if (preg_match('/'.$urlregex.'/i', $url))
```

Comment: This one works but not 100%: if (preg_match("(".$urlregex.")i", $url))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't work because the char you're using as delimiter (ie. `#`) is present in the regex.

You can:

- escape the `#` in the regex: `\#`
- change the delimiter to a char that is not present in the regex

Answer (score 0):

try this :-

```
$url = "https://james.wordpress.com/2013/05/13/my-product-final";
if (preg_match("/^(https?:\/\/+[\w\-]+\.[\w\-]+)/i",$url))
{
echo "Valid";
exit;
}
```

[filter_var()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function can also validate whether a string is URL or not

Answer (score 0):

```
$website = "http://googl.com";

if (!preg_match("/\b(?:(?:https?|ftp):\/\/|www\.)[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-a-z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|]/i",$website))
  {
  $websiteErr = "Invalid URL"; 
  }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.

Comment: The user tried to convert into 'preg_match' but it couldn't work so this one will work with him.